# Como paso un array de una pagina a otra en ionic

Tags: array, angular, formularios, ionic

tengo un array con nombres de jugadores, simples strings y no se como puedo pasarlo a la siguiente página

aquí relleno el array desde el myform:

```
public Players: Array<string> = new Array();

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){

    this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
      player1: ['', Validators.required]
    });

  }
  addControl(){
    this.Players.push(this.myForm.controls['player'+this.playerCount].value);
    console.log(this.Players);
    this.playerCount++;
    this.myForm.addControl('player' + this.playerCount, new FormControl('', Validators.required));
  }
```

este es el service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { IPlayers } from "../interfaces";

@Injectable()

export class PlayersService {
    Players: IPlayers [

    ]
    getPlayers(): IPlayers[]{
        return this.Players;
    }
}
```

y esta es la otra pagina donde quiero que llegue el array, pero no llega

```
export class VerdadORetoPage implements OnInit {

players: IPlayers[];

  constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private _PlayersService: PlayersService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.players=this._PlayersService.getPlayers();
    console.log(this.players);
  }

}
```

es una pregunta un poco burra pero estoy aprendiendo ionic, no me juzgen jeje, gracias de antemano

Comment: si hay alguna forma de pasar el valor desde el myform tambien me vale, pienso que sería lo logico y que no es necesario un array para esto jajaja

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas hacer es en el servicio crear la función

```
setPlayers(players: IPlayers ) {
  this.Players = players
}
```

Luego, en el primer componente, antes de navegar hacia la siguiente pagina, updatea los players del servicio compartido

```
this._PlayersService.setPlayers(this.Players);
```

Recuerda que ademas, tienes que inyectar PlayersService en el constructor como lo hiciste en el segundo

```
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _PlayersService: PlayersService)
```

Finalmente, en el segundo componente deberias tener disponibles los players que cargaste en el primero.